# How to split a list into sublists with specific range for each sublist?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, sorting

I want to split a list into sublist with specific 'if statement' for each sublist.
For examle:
input:

```
a = [1, 2, 7.9, 3, 4, 3.7, 5, 6, 2.2, 7, 8, 1.2, 5.7]
```

output:

```
b = [[1, 1.2, 2], [2.2, 3, 3.7, 4], [5, 5.7, 6], [7, 7.9, 8]]
```

Values should be grouped by certain range. here it is between (1:2); (2.1:4); (4.1:6); (6.1:8). I hope I was able to get my point across.

Comment: Are you asking how to create a list of lists from a list? Your question is not clear. Please edit and repost.

Comment: Don't repost. Just edit your question

Comment: The logic is unclear, can you describe how the values should be grouped?

Comment: I apologize for not being able to convey my problem clearly.

Comment: @Salkynbekov you might want to look into [tag:pandas] and its `cut` method. It provides a high level function to group values in bins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to divide your data into buckets of width `dx`. Assuming this, your expected output would be:

```
[[1, 1.2, 2], [2.2, 3], [3.7, 4], [5, 5.7, 6], [7, 7.9, 8]]
```

First, let's sort the input numbers:

```
numbers = sorted(a)
```

Now, we'll iterate over this sorted list, and append to a `bucket` list as long as appending the current number wouldn't exceed our desired range for this bucket. If appending the current number would cause the desired range to be exceeded, then we create a new bucket and start appending to it:

```
bucket = []
result = [bucket]
for n in numbers:
    # bucket is empty, or bucket range <= dx, so append
    if not bucket or n - bucket[0] <= dx: 
        bucket.append(n)
    else:
        bucket = [n] # Create a new bucket with the current number
        result.append(bucket) # Add it to our result array
```

This gives your expected result:

```
result = [[1, 1.2, 2], [2.2, 3], [3.7, 4], [5, 5.7, 6], [7, 7.9, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic is not fully clear. Assuming you want to group by bins of width 2 (1-2, 3-4, 5-6, ...) with the right boundary included.

We can use a dictionary to temporarily hold the bins and to facilitate the creation of the sublists.

```
from math import ceil

a = [1, 2, 7.9, 3, 4, 3.7, 5, 6, 2.2, 7, 8, 1.2, 5.7]
dx = 2

d = {}

for x in sorted(a):
    k = ceil(x+1)//dx
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(x)

b = list(d.values())
```

Output:

```
[[1, 1.2, 2], [2.2, 3, 3.7, 4], [5, 5.7, 6], [7, 7.9, 8]]
```